# How to open a new tab/page using ButtonField in GridView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID ="FileGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="FileGrid_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OriginalFileName" HeaderText="OriginalFileName" SortExpression="OriginalFileName" /> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AttachmentGUID" HeaderText="AttachmentGUID" SortExpression="AttachmentGUID" />             
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Generate PDF" runat="server" HeaderText="Convert To PDF" CommandName="GeneratePDF_Click" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void FileGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "GeneratePDF_Click")
    {
        int num = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument);
        string attachmentGuid = FileGrid.Rows[num].Cells[1].Text;
        Response.Redirect("DisplayImage.aspx?AttachmentGUID=" + attachmentGuid);
    }
}
```

I see a lot of solutions using `OnClientClick` with a `asp:Button`, but I'm unable to use a `asp:Button` within a column?

Comment: this answer could help you http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_24005382.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` to open up a new window:

```
var url = "DisplayImage.aspx?AttachmentGUID=" + attachmentGuid;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('" + url + "','_blank')", true);
```

or you can also try:

```
var url = "DisplayImage.aspx?AttachmentGUID=" + attachmentGuid;
string redirect = "<script>window.open('" + url + "');</script>"; 
Response.Write(redirect);
```

Comment: Yeah there are few different ways to do this. You're welcome.